# Understanding Getchar unlocked

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am kind of a novice in competitive programming and I find that many guys use the following snippet of code in almost every submission that they make.

```
#define gc getchar_unlocked
int readint()

{
    int f=0,ret=0;
    char c=gc();
    while(c<'0'||c>'9')
        c=gc();
    while(c>='0'&&c<='9')
    {
        ret=ret*10+c-48;
        c=gc();
    }
    return f?-ret:ret;
}
```

Does this code ensure fast I/O.What is the logic of using this in competitive programming and other applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this code will be in most cases more efficient than standard library implementations. It makes more assumptions about the input, which makes it more fragile, but allows for additional optimizations. These assumptions are: numbers are always decimal, separated by single non-digit character, any second separating character is always minus, numbers are always small enough to fit in an `int`. These assumptions are acceptable in programming contest, but in most cases should not be used otherwise.

`getchar` is simply a functions that returns a single character from buffered input. `_unlocked` is a version that skips synchronization and can faster, but will result in unpredictable behavior in case of multiple threads reading input.

This code could potentially be made even faster by doing buffering on ones own and avoiding library call for every character. It is probably not worth it to do this though.